# What is the name of this horror film where a man grows another head?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

I'm looking for the name of a horror movie or part of an anthology (Chiller/Thriller?) when I was a kid in the 1960's. I just remember a man develops an eye on the side of his neck and it grows into a full-size head.

Comment: Can you not remember anything else at all about this? Any of the plot? How did the man develop the eye? What happens after? Please [edit] anything, at all, that you can remember.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Runner-up: *Army of Darkness*, which apparently stole that scene from the real answer.... "Oh, dear God, it's growing bigger!"

Answer (score 10):

Could this be [*The Manster*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Manster) (1959)?

> ... a foreign correspondent in Japan who is given an experimental drug which causes an eye and eventually, a second head to grow from his shoulder.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure about the date? Sounds a lot like this film, but it's too late.

[How to Get Ahead in Advertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Get_Ahead_in_Advertising) (1989)

> The film is a farce about a mentally unstable advertising executive, Denis Dimbleby Bagley (played by Grant), who suffers a nervous breakdown while making an advert for pimple cream...
>
> He then develops a boil on his right shoulder that comes to life with a face and voice. ...
>
> Bagley decides to have the boil removed in hospital but moments before he is taken into the operating room, the boil quickly grows into a replica of Bagley's head (only with a moustache) and covers Bagley's original head,